# Why I am not able to control Media volume when the alert dialog is shown in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am controlling  media volume programmatically from my app. I am setting alert dialog when the media volume is below certain range. When this alert is displayed at this point if I try to adjust the volume controller buttons the ringer volume will get adjusted not media volume.
Why is this happening?

I am using these lines to control media volume..

```
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:

             audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
             return true;
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:

             audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);

             return true;
```

Once the alert dialog is dismissed I am able to control the media volume.
I am facing this issue only in phone not in tablet.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to call [Dialog.setVolumeControlStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setVolumeControlStream%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

How about just letting the phone control the volume on its own?  That's pretty much how the designers thought [developer-managing-audio-volume](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html#PlaybackControls).  Saves you a lot of trouble.  All you have to do is add this line to the onCreate() of each Activity:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

If you want to intercept the volume and add a warning if it goes past a thresh-hold, go ahead.  It should still work.